# How to lock down a branch, but still allow certain users to check-in?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

What I intend to do is lock the whole release branch down so nobody can do check-in.

But there's one developer that does a lot of installer changes, so he has to be able to submit changes.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are an admin for the project: right-click a folder (in your case, your branch root) in source control explorer, click "Advanced/Security" in the menu, and then choose your settings. You may wish to create a new user group, or just add the user individually.

As a side note, it's often more user-friendly if you deny lock and check-in rights (rather than denying check *out*): if a developer is browsing the code, VS will often try to check out various files, and the error dialogs this shows when security-blocked can be quite intrusive.

Comment: Thanks. I re-organized the user groups in TFS and denied most ppl of their check-in permission. And added a few exceptions that has that check-in permission. Look like I can't simple lock the whole branch down.